# Highlight dates in specific range with jQuery's datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date, highlight

I need to highlight the dates between a start date and an end date, which I should be able to specify. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry need more. Your wanting to highlight a range or just the 2 dates?  Are you using the jquery ui datepicker or have you built your own?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Need to highlight range of dates in jquery datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317396/need-to-highlight-range-of-dates-in-jquery-datepicker) (Or other way around?)

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [beforeShowDay event](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).  It will get called for each date that needs to be shown in the calendar. It passes in a date and return an array with `[0]= isSelectable, [1]= cssClass, [2]=Some tooltip text`

```
$('#whatever').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
             if (date == myDate) {
              return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'tooltipText'];
              }else{
              //this will allow the cell be selected without been highlighted
              return [true,'']
              }
           }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to return [true, ''] if you don't want to highlight a day: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9358119/664132

Comment: how the parameter "date" is initialized what is the start and end date of that value for function(date) ?

Answer (score 25):

Here's a working example! You will nees to make a package from here with http://jqueryui.com/download with core, widget and datepicker.

The javascript part to put before :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dates = ['22/01/2012', '23/01/2012']; //
            //tips are optional but good to have
    var tips  = ['some description','some other description'];      

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({                
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
    });

    function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
                return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
     } 

});
</script>
```

The HTML part:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Add somewhere this CSS:

```
    td.highlight {border: none !important;padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;background: none !important;overflow:hidden;}
td.highlight a {background: #99dd73 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;}
```

And you will need to make a small image called bg.png to make it work

Comment: But that does not change the bgcolor of the date, only of the table cell where we can just see the edge.

Comment: You will have to add another piece of CSS code to specify also the color of the <a> tag inside your element like this

 `.highlight a {
  background: red; 
} `

Now there are going to be both red :)

Comment: I tried. Did not work with that selector -  Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023818/correct-way-to-change-specific-dates-cell-background-color-on-datepicker

Comment: Fabulous - been having problems setting the background colour of specific cells. Your css has resolved this. Thx

Answer (score 14):

Thought I would throw in my two cents as it seems faster and more light weight than others:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var dates = {
    '2012/6/4': 'some description',
    '2012/6/6': 'some other description'
  };

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var search = date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();

      if (search in dates) {
        return [true, 'highlight', (dates[search] || '')];
      }

      return [false, '', ''];
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - copy and paste.  Great job @mark-murphy !

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will be still useful, but as this was useful to me, I want to share what I did:

In my JavaScript:

```
var holidays= ["2016/09/18", "2016/09/19", "2016/01/01", "2016/05/01", "2016/06/27", "2016/08/15"];

$("#SomeID").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: highLight });

function highLight(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(holidays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-holiday'];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
```

And in the jquery-ui-theme.css I've added

```
.ui-state-holiday .ui-state-default {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to highlight weekends also, you have to use this CSS instead

```
.ui-state-holiday .ui-state-default, .ui-datepicker-week-end .ui-state-default {
    color: red;
}
```

And this is the result:
[image: jqueryUI Calendar with Weekends and Holidays Highlight]

(Note that I have configured my language to spanish, but this is not important to this code)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Keith Wood's [datepick](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) you can use the following example taken from [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html)

```
$(selector).datepick({onDate: highlightDays}); 

function highlightDays(date) { 
    return {selectable: true, dateClass: 'highlight-custom', title: 'tooltip'}; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's a JSFiddle that I used to test:

https://jsfiddle.net/gq6kdoc9/

HTML:

```
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var dates = ['11/13/2017', '11/14/2017'];
   //tips are optional but good to have
   var tips = ['some description', 'some other description'];

   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
     showOtherMonths: true,
     numberOfMonths: 3,
   });

   function highlightDays(date) {
     for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
       if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
         return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
       }
     }
     return [true, ''];
   }
```

And CSS:

```
td.highlight {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
  background: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.highlight a {
  background: #ad3f29 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}
```

Built on Mike's working example above!

Answer (score 0):

mugur, your code didn't quite work for me in Firefox or Safari, it required the `date` var to be formatted (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)). Here

```
function highlightDays(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

var d = date.getDate();
var m =  date.getMonth();
m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
var y = date.getFullYear();

var dateToCheck = (d + "/" + m + "/" + y);
    if (dates[i] == dateToCheck) {
        return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
    }
    }
return [true, ''];
}
```

And, of course, as the above function stands it doesn't account for leading-zeroes padding so the `dates` array needed to be changed to:

```
var dates = ['22/1/2014', '23/1/2014'];
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me.What if the date I have is in '31/08/2015' format ??

Comment: I'm not at a computer but off the top of my head, I'd split the date into day, month, year components and recombine to pass into this function. Chances are that the splitting process will cause the '08' to become just '8'. Alternatively wouldn't Mugur's answer work?