# jQuery date formatting

Tags: jquery

How can I format the date using jQuery. I am using below code but getting error:

```
 $("#txtDate").val($.format.date(new Date(), 'dd M yy'));
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$.format' is null or not an object

Comment: have you included the plugin that includes the format functions?

Comment: Sneaky one liner for yyyy-mm-dd: `new Date().toJSON().substring(0,10)`

Comment: it's fformat (double f)

Comment: Mike Causer, you're a genius!

Comment: Mike Causer, brilliant. If you want time as well then you can do this: `new Date().toJSON().substring(0,19).replace('T',' ');`

Comment: WARNING! the slick code: `new Date().toJSON().substring(0,10)` worked nice, but it returns date as GMT!  Since we are 7 hours behind GMT, I was getting the wrong date after 5:00pm. I just wasted a couple hours finding the cause /sigh/.  [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646446/javascript-date-tojson-produces-a-date-which-has-wrong-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: Mike Causer you rock. `new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10)`

Comment: @JayRO-GreyBeard, one liner with timezoneOffset: `new Date().toLocaleDateString();`. Converts the date portion of a Date object into a readable string

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Dotnet sure, using other functions: See e.g. [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

Comment: I dont want to use plugin. CAn you please tell me how can I format the date ?

Comment: @Dotnet see the link in my comment

Comment: @Dotnet if it could be done using jQuery, there would not be a jQuery plug-in for date formatting, would there?

Comment: I can't tell if this should be a joke or not... it's almost brilliant @pekka. Also, it's the right answer.

Comment: jQuery dateFormat doesn't works with jQuery Validate. Neither the pure JavaScript version.

Comment: It is hard to believe that vanilla jQuery doesn't have a function to format a date. This question is 5 years old, is this still the case?

Comment: @felwithe a cursory Google search suggests that indeed is the case! Perhaps they felt it's functionality they want to keep out of the core library for bandwidth and performance reasons.

Answer (score 223):

**add  jquery ui plugin in your page.**

```
 $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date()));
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, especially since I am using jQuery UI elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any way to get date + 2 years ?

Comment: var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 2);

Comment: it is a pitty that it doesnt support time formatting =S

Comment: Here's the link to the official doc : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: what a strange library. 'dd M yy' is understood as 'dd MMM yyyy'.
This library has it's own understanding of format

Answer (score 108):

An alternative would be simple js date() function, if you don't want to use jQuery/jQuery plugin:

e.g.:

```
var formattedDate = new Date("yourUnformattedOriginalDate");
var d = formattedDate.getDate();
var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();

$("#txtDate").val(d + "." + m + "." + y);
```

see: [10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

If you want to add leading zeros to day/month, this is a perfect example:
[Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

and if you want to add time with leading zeros try this:
[getMinutes() 0-9 - how to with two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935414/getminutes-0-9-how-to-with-two-numbers)

Comment: it will be handy to add seconds as @sein did

Comment: This is good until the user wants the recent date or a date is fed into the `Date` object. What about getting the date in the same format but 6 months prior to the fed date ??

Answer (score 40):

Here's a really basic function I just made that doesn't require any external plugins:

```
$.date = function(dateObject) {
    var d = new Date(dateObject);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    return date;
};
```

Use:

```
$.date(yourDateObject);
```

Result:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Comment: thanks super cool easy to use I tried working perfectly

Comment: superb Solution

Answer (score 32):

I'm using [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/). Is very helpful and easy to use.

```
var date = moment(); //Get the current date
date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"); //2014-07-10
```

Answer (score 29):

ThulasiRam, I prefer your suggestion. It works well for me in a slightly different syntax/context:

```
var dt_to = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());
```

If you decide to utilize datepicker from [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats), make sure you use proper references in your document's < head > section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 17):

I hope this code will fix your problem.

```
var d = new Date();

var curr_day = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();

curr_month++ ; // In js, first month is 0, not 1
year_2d = curr_year.toString().substring(2, 4)

$("#txtDate").val(curr_day + " " + curr_month + " " + year_2d)
```

Answer (score 10):

Add this function to your `<script></script>` and call from where ever you want in that `<script></script>`

```
<script>

function GetNow(){
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "-"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "-" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
    return datetime;
}

window.alert(GetNow());

</script>
```

or you may simply use the Jquery which provides formatting facilities also:-

```
window.alert(Date.parse(new Date()).toString('yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s'));
```

I love the second option. It resolves all issues in one go.

Comment: That 2nd option gives me "radix argument must be between 2 and 36
    at Number.toString". It crashes.

Comment: We can't use second option as it will throw error

Answer (score 9):

If you are using jquery ui then you may use it like below, you can specify your own date format

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "D dd-M-yy", new Date()) // Output "Fri 08-Sep-2017"
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use this:

```
var date_str=('0'+date.getDate()).substr(-2,2)+' '+('0'+date.getMonth()).substr(-2,2)+' '+('0'+date.getFullYear()).substr(-2,2);
```

Comment: Note, this gives you a date one month in the past (unless it's accessed in January in which case it gives you '00' for the month) because date.getMonth() is a zero-based index.

Answer (score 6):

Though this question was asked a few years ago, a jQuery plugin isn't required anymore provided the date value in question is a string with format `mm/dd/yyyy` (like when using a date-picker);

```
var birthdateVal = $('#birthdate').val();
//birthdateVal: 11/8/2014

var birthdate = new Date(birthdateVal);
//birthdate: Sat Nov 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add new user jQuery function 'getDate'

JSFiddle: [getDate jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/getx9n3b/)

Or you can run code snippet. Just press "Run code snippet" button below this post.

```js
// Create user jQuery function 'getDate'
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.getDate = function(format) {

 var gDate  = new Date();
 var mDate  = {
 'S': gDate.getSeconds(),
 'M': gDate.getMinutes(),
 'H': gDate.getHours(),
 'd': gDate.getDate(),
 'm': gDate.getMonth() + 1,
 'y': gDate.getFullYear(),
 }

 // Apply format and add leading zeroes
 return format.replace(/([SMHdmy])/g, function(key){return (mDate[key] < 10 ? '0' : '') + mDate[key];});

 return getDate(str);
   }; 
})( jQuery );


// Usage: example #1. Write to '#date' div
$('#date').html($().getDate("y-m-d H:M:S"));

// Usage: ex2. Simple clock. Write to '#clock' div
function clock(){
 $('#clock').html($().getDate("H:M:S, m/d/y"))
}
clock();
setInterval(clock, 1000); // One second

// Usage: ex3. Simple clock 2. Write to '#clock2' div
function clock2(){

 var format = 'H:M:S'; // Date format
 var updateInterval = 1000; // 1 second
 var clock2Div = $('#clock2'); // Get div
 var currentTime = $().getDate(format); // Get time
 
 clock2Div.html(currentTime); // Write to div
 setTimeout(clock2, updateInterval); // Set timer 1 second
 
}
// Run clock2
clock2();

// Just for fun
// Usage: ex4. Simple clock 3. Write to '#clock3' span

function clock3(){

 var formatHM = 'H:M:'; // Hours, minutes
 var formatS = 'S'; // Seconds
 var updateInterval = 1000; // 1 second
 var clock3SpanHM = $('#clock3HM'); // Get span HM
 var clock3SpanS = $('#clock3S'); // Get span S
 var currentHM = $().getDate(formatHM); // Get time H:M
 var currentS = $().getDate(formatS); // Get seconds
 
 clock3SpanHM.html(currentHM); // Write to div
 clock3SpanS.fadeOut(1000).html(currentS).fadeIn(1); // Write to span
 setTimeout(clock3, updateInterval); // Set timer 1 second
 
}
// Run clock2
clock3();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date"></div><br>
<div id="clock"></div><br>
<span id="clock3HM"></span><span id="clock3S"></span>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of this snippet

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1900:+0',
  defaultDate: '01 JAN 1900',
  buttonImage: "http://www.theplazaclub.com/club/images/calendar/outlook_calendar.gif",
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: function() {
    $('#datepicker').val($(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>
  selector: <input type="text" class="datepicker">
</p>
<p>
  output: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply we can format the date like,

```
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();
var date1 = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + date.getFullYear();
$("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(date1)));
```

Where "date" is a date in any format.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mbitto/jquery.i18Now

This jQuery plugin helps you to format and translate date and time according to your preference.

Answer (score 2):

Use dateFormat option when creating date picker.

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below code without the plugin.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
$( function() {
    //call the function on page load
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    //set the date format here
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option" , "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
 
    // you also can use 
    // yy-mm-dd
    // d M, y
    // d MM, y
    // DD, d MM, yy
    // &apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy (With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy)
 } );
 </script>

Pick the Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://www.datejs.com/

```
 $('#idInput').val( Date.parse("Jun 18, 2017 7:00:00 PM").toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

BR

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with slight modification and without any plugin

Input : Wed Apr 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000

```
$.date = function(orginaldate) { 
    var date = new Date(orginaldate);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date =  month + "/" + day + "/" + year; 
    return date;
};

$.date('Wed Apr 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000')
```

Output: 04/11/2018

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved through this, I have resolved this without any plugin or datepicker.

```js
GetDatePattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
 function GetDatePattern(pattern)
    {
    var monthNames=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    
            var todayDate = new Date();
                                              
                            var date = todayDate.getDate().toString();
                            var month = todayDate.getMonth().toString(); 
                            var year = todayDate.getFullYear().toString(); 
                            var formattedMonth = (todayDate.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + month : month;
                            var formattedDay = (todayDate.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + date : date;
                            var result = "";
    
                            switch (pattern) {
                                case "M/d/yyyy": 
                                    formattedMonth = formattedMonth.indexOf("0") == 0 ? formattedMonth.substring(1, 2) : formattedMonth;
                                    formattedDay = formattedDay.indexOf("0") == 0 ? formattedDay.substring(1, 2) : formattedDay;
    
                                    result  = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDay + '/' + year;
                                    break;
    
                                case "M/d/yy": 
                                    formattedMonth = formattedMonth.indexOf("0") == 0 ? formattedMonth.substring(1, 2) : formattedMonth;
                                    formattedDay = formattedDay.indexOf("0") == 0 ? formattedDay.substring(1, 2) : formattedDay;
                                    result  = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDay + '/' + year.substr(2);
                                    break;
    
                                case "MM/dd/yy":
                                    result  = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDay + '/' + year.substr(2);
                                    break;
    
                                case "MM/dd/yyyy":
                                   result  = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDay + '/' + year;
                                    break;
    
                                case "yy/MM/dd":
                                    result  = year.substr(2) + '/' + formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDay;
                                    break;
    
    
                                case "yyyy-MM-dd":
                                    result  = year + '-' + formattedMonth + '-' + formattedDay;
                                    break;
    
                                case "dd-MMM-yy":
                                   result  = formattedDay + '-' + monthNames[todayDate.getMonth()].substr(3) + '-' + year.substr(2);
                                    break;
    
                                case "MMMM d, yyyy":
                                    result  = todayDate.toLocaleDateString("en-us", { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' });
                                    break;
    
    
                            }
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I'm allowed to answer a question that was asked like 2 years ago as this is my first answer on stackoverflow but, here's my solution;

If you once retrieved the date from your MySQL database, split it and then use the splitted values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datefrommysql = $('.date-from-mysql').attr("date");
    var arraydate = datefrommysql.split('.');
    var yearfirstdigit = arraydate[2][2];
    var yearlastdigit = arraydate[2][3];
    var day = arraydate[0];
    var month = arraydate[1];
    $('.formatted-date').text(day + "/" + month + "/" + yearfirstdigit + yearlastdigit);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terby/zRP7M/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code example I have show on browser, Hope you also helpful thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                minDate: -100,
                maxDate: "+0D",
                dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
                onSelect: function(datetext){
                    $(this).val(datetext);
                },
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

using Moment JS
[moment js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
$("#YourDateInput").val(moment($("#YourDateInput").val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Answer (score -1):

u can use this coding

```
$('[name="tgllahir"]').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date(data.tgllahir)));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the many other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Also, this question is 6 years old, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer didn't mention jQuery UI was required