# How to convert default date in to isoDate Using Jquery

Tags: date, system, isodate

How can I convert the the SystemDate `Wed Jan 25 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (COT)` into isoDate `2011-01-01` using Jquery, can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jQuery dateFormat](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) plugin.

see [jQuery date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting) for more info