# getMinutes() 0-9 - How to display two digit numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
var date = "2012-01-18T16:03";
var date = new Date(date);

console.log(date.getMinutes());
console.log(date.getMinutes().length)
```

This returns 3.

1. How do I make it return '03'?
2. Why does `.length` return undefinded?

I tried this, but it did not work:

If `strlen == 1` then `num = ('0' + num);`

Comment: Just to add up, the return of `.getMinutes()` is an integer, you can't access `.length` from an integer. To accomplish that (not recommended when dealing with dates) is parsing the number to a string and then checking the length. E.g.: `date.getMinutes().toString().length`

Answer (score 348, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("2012-01-18T16:03");

console.log( (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes() );
```

Comment: What does this `<10?'0':''` mean?

Comment: @user1063287 it is an inline if else statement

Comment: @user1063287 It means: "If getMinutes() is less than 10, return a 0, if greater, return an empty string.

Comment: @user1063287 see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: (condition?true:false) in PHP you can omit the true statement (condition?:false) in JS you would then use (condition||false) Ternary operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: Putting this here for a common mistake: if this looks like it doesn't work, you might have missed the brackets surrounding the ternary operators, you'd get weird results without them. DON"T DO THIS: `date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "" + date.getMinutes()`

Answer (score 249):

This solution is cross-browser and cleaner int/string conversion. My advice is to not use a variable named 'date' with code like `date = Date(...)` where you're relying heavily on language case sensitivity (it works, but risky when you're working with server/browser code in different languages with different rules). So assuming the JavaScript Date in a var `current_date`:

```
mins = ('0'+current_date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

The technique is take the rightmost 2 characters `(slice(-2))` of "0" prepended onto the string value of `getMinutes()`. So:

```
"0"+"12" -> "012".slice(-2) -> "12"
```

and

```
"0"+"1" -> "01".slice(-2) -> "01"
```

Answer (score 110):

Another short way is to fill the minutes with a leading zero using:

```
String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0");
```

Meaning: Make the string two chars long, if a char is missing then set `0` at this position.

See docs at [str.padStart(targetLength, padString)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: While I really liked this answer, it unfortunately didn't work for me (in Tasker Jslet, for the record). The accepted answer is workaround-ish, but fool-proof!

Comment: I don't comment on SO often but I felt compelled to say that this is the correct answer for the issue at hand. For an integer there is no difference between 5 and 05, it only matters when you want to treat the value as a string, in which case using string functions is what you need to do.

Answer (score 20):

Elegant ES6 function to format a date into `hh:mm:ss`:

```
const leadingZero = (num) => `0${num}`.slice(-2);

const formatTime = (date) =>
  [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()]
  .map(leadingZero)
  .join(':');
```

Answer (score 16):

Using ECMAScript Internationalization API, [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```js
const date_string = "2012-01-18T16:03";
const date = new Date(date_string);
const twoDigitMinutes = date.toLocaleString("en-us", {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: "2-digit"});

console.log(twoDigitMinutes);
```

Comment: Came here in Nov 2020 and this is the safest answer!

Comment: This works for printing out the full timestamp, but if you just want the minutes(or the seconds) by themselves, it won't print 2 digit! If you only include `minute: '2-digit'` in the curly braces, it just prints `3` instead of `03`. Any tips on how to get the `03` just using the `Date` object functions?

Answer (score 13):

I would like to provide a more neat solution to the problem if I may.The accepted answer is very good. But I would have done it like this.

```
Date.prototype.getFullMinutes = function () {
   if (this.getMinutes() < 10) {
       return '0' + this.getMinutes();
   }
   return this.getMinutes();
};
```

Now if you want to use this.

```
console.log(date.getFullMinutes());
```

Answer (score 10):

I suggest:

```
var minutes = data.getMinutes();
minutes = minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
```

it is one function call fewer. It is always good to think about performance.
It is short as well;

Answer (score 7):

I assume you would need the value as string. You could use the code below.
It will always return give you the two digit minutes as string.

```js
const date_string = "2012-01-18T16:03";
const date = new Date(date_string);
let min = date.getMinutes();

if (min < 10) { // or min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
   min = '0' + min;
} else {
   min = min + '';
}

console.log(min);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

how about this? it works for me! :)

```
var d = new Date();
var minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
var dateTime = new Date();
var minutesTwoDigitsWithLeadingZero = ("0" + dateTime.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems IE8 and earlier versions don't support negative numbers for `substr`. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Answer (score 4):

you should check if it is less than 10... not looking for the length of it , because this is a number and not a string

Answer (score 3):

`.length` is undefined because `getMinutes` is returning a number, not a string. numbers don't have a `length` property.  You could do

`var m = "" + date.getMinutes();`

to make it a string, **then** check the length (you would want to check for `length === 1`, not 0).

Answer (score 3):

Numbers don't have a length, but you can easily convert the number to a string, check the length and then prepend the 0 if it's necessary:

```
var strMonth = '' + date.getMinutes();
if (strMonth.length == 1) {
  strMonth = '0' + strMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont see any ES6 answers on here so I will add one using StandardJS formatting

```
// ES6 String formatting example
const time = new Date()
const tempMinutes = new Date.getMinutes()
const minutes = (tempMinutes < 10) ? `0${tempMinutes}` : tempMinutes
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const date_string = "2012-01-18T16:03";
const date = new Date(date_string);
const dd = date.getDate();
const MM = date.getMonth();
const mm = date.getMinutes();
const HH = date.getHours();

// Year
const year = date.getFullYear();

// Month
const month = ("0" + (MM + 1)).slice(-2); // first month start from 0, so add +1

// Day
const day = ("0" + dd).slice(-2);

// Hour
const hour = ("0" + HH).slice(-2);

// Minutes
const minutes = ("0" + mm).slice(-2);

// Seconds
const seconds = ("0" + mm).slice(-2);

console.log(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this piece of code :

```
var start = new Date(timestamp),
    startMinutes = start.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + start.getMinutes() : start.getMinutes();
```

It is quite similar to the @ogur accepted answer but does not concatenate an empty string in the case that 0 is not needed. Not sure it is better. Just an other way to do it !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".min").append( (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes() );
```

new to JS so this was very helpful
the most ppl looking at this prob new too
so this is how i got it to show in the div called "class="min"

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get two digit minutes or hours.

```
var date = new Date("2012-01-18T16:03");

var minutes = date.toTimeString().slice(3, 5); 
var hours   = date.toTimeString().slice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) :

> `moment(date).format('mm')`

example : `moment('2019-10-29T21:08').format('mm') ==> 08`

hope it helps someone

**Link github**:
https://github.com/moment/moment/

Comment: very nice when one anyways is using moment, thank you :-)

Answer (score -1):

For two digit minutes use:
`new Date().toLocaleFormat("%M")`

Comment: This is depreciated - do not use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat

Answer (score -4):

If you're using AngularJS in your project, just inject $filter and use it like here:

```
$filter('date')(value, 'HH:mm')
```

You can also format the output in the template, more on filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).