# Displaying integers with string returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to do a fancy clock with HTML. But there is a part where I want to display like`00 : 00`.  But returns `NaN`. 
Here is the code:

```js
var update;

function updateFunc() {
  update = setInterval(myDate, 1000);
}

function myDate() {  
    var newDate = new Date();
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML  = newDate;
}

function updateClock() {
  var update = setInterval(clockTime, 1000);
}

function clockTime() {
  var  hours = (new Date()).getHours();
  var  minutes = (new Date()).getMinutes(); 
    var  seconds = (new Date()).getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("clockMins").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds; //this is my problem. 
}

updateFunc();
updateClock();
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">#myDiv</div>
<div id="clockMins"></div>
```

Ps. How I can display the integers in two digits. Ex. 00, 01. 02.

Comment: Please add the rest of your code - what is your HTML? What is `minutes`? What is `seconds`?

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with that code (although it should be included with the question rather than put as a comment).

Comment: please include relevant html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Comment: edited as proposed by reader with inclusion of html and calls to code - unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @traktor53 there is no problem in code, it's all about 01:02 in output minutes and seconds instead of 1:2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getMinutes() 0-9 - How to display two digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935414/getminutes-0-9-how-to-display-two-digit-numbers)

Answer (score -4):

```js
var update; 
function n(n){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
}
function updateFunc() { 
    update = setInterval(myDate, 1000); 
} 

function myDate() { 
    var newDate = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = newDate; 
} 

function updateClock() { 
    var update = setInterval(clockTime, 1000); 
} 

function clockTime() { 
    var hours = (new Date()).getHours(); 
    var minutes = (new Date()).getMinutes(); 
    var seconds = (new Date()).getSeconds(); 
    var seperator = ':'; 
    document.getElementById("clockMins").innerHTML = n(minutes) + ":"+ n(seconds); 
}
clockTime();
updateClock();
```

```html
<div id="clockMins"></div>
```

Comment: nice Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V :)

Comment: w3schools.com haha