# Clock keeps using one digit

Tags: javascript, html

I asked about a day ago how to make a clock. The code I'm using works, but instead of going from `18:59:59` to `19:00:00`, it goes from `18:59:59` to `19:0:0`. How would I add a zero upfront if something is a single digit, so instead of `19:0:0`, it becomes `19:00:00`? Here is the code I'm using.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    let i = 5;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;

        i--;
        if (i < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getMinutes() 0-9 - How to display two digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935414/getminutes-0-9-how-to-display-two-digit-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    let i = 5;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        var date = new Date();
        var time = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;

        i--;
        if (i < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `padStart` which exists for exactly this purpose: `var time = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, '0')).join(':')`