# How to format date fetched by JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am fetching and displaying date from sql server database using Jquery now the problem is that this is what I am getting in my HTML

```
2013-05-30T10:05:00+05:30
```

I would like it to be something like `2013-05-30 10:05:00` or just `10:05:00`

**NO PLUG-IN PLZ**

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can process the outcome in javascript

such that

```
var s='2013-05-30T10:05:00+05:30';
var time_vl=s.split('T')[1].split('+')[0];
```

that will give you your output

Comment: Can you also explain it a bit like what is [1] and [0] for?

Comment: well split actually splits a string where ever it finds its argument in your case s.split('T') will return an array with two items in it [0] will be 2013-05-30 and [1] will be 10:05:00+05:30 , here we took [1] and splited it again by calling s.split('T')[1].split('+') smilarly here we will have two items [0] will be 10:05:00 , and [1] will be 05:30

Answer (score 0):

you should format the DateTime string in your C# code before passing the results to the client side.

Answer (score -1):

You can add JQuery UI Plugin in your page :

```
$("#DateField").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date()));
```

Comment: The OP requires the time portion