# How to change date format using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

I have a date in a format like this `fecha2.value = '2014-01-06'`, but I want to change the format to this `'01-06-14'` using jQuery.

How can I do this?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any date-specific functions. It looks like you should be able to do this just using simple Javascript string operations. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Answer (score 63):

You can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date('2014-01-06');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Alternatively, you can do it natively like this:

```js
var dateAr = '2014-01-06'.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[0].slice(-2);

console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: how can we do this on a plane javascript?

Comment: The second example is using plain Javascript

Comment: I would use split if you can. I just had an issue with days and months getting mixed up.

Answer (score 7):

```
var d = new Date();

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

curr_year = curr_year.toString().substr(2,2);

document.write(curr_date+"-"+curr_month+"-"+curr_year);
```

You can change this as your need..

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any date-specific functions for this, it's just string manipulation:

```
var parts = fecha2.value.split('-');
var newdate = parts[1]+'-'+parts[2]+'-'+(parseInt(parts[0], 10)%100);
```

Answer (score 6):

I dont think you need to use jQuery at all, just simple JavaScript...

Save the date as a string:

```
dte = fecha.value;//2014-01-06
```

Split the string to get the day, month & year values...

```
dteSplit = dte.split("-");
yr = dteSplit[0][2] + dteSplit[0][3]; //special yr format, take last 2 digits
month = dteSplit[1];
day = dteSplit[2];
```

Rejoin into final date string:

```
finalDate = month+"-"+day+"-"+year
```

Answer (score 1):

In most  projects you want to use **moment.js** library  along with **datepicker** and **datetimepicker**s .

It doesnt look that verbose. For example

```
let dateString_ = moment('2023-01-17T13:39:48.530801Z').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

for `2023-01-17 18:39`

[Formatting rules are here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)