# How to reverse date format yyyy-mm-dd using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to change the date for of data which is in format `2016-10-15` to `d-m-yy` format in jquery as `15-10-2016`.I tried and console the output it shows `2016-10-15`.I caught this result in jquery ajax page which is fetched from database.

```
$.each(req,function(i,item){
    var val=$.format.date(req[i].from_date, "dd/MMM/yyyy");
    console.log(val);   //'2016-10-15'
});
```

Comment: You can get it from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946475/how-to-change-date-format-using-jquery

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this work use native javascript functions. Use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split date by `-` delimiter into array and invert array using [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and convert array to sting using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var date = "2016-10-15";
date = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do in javascript like this:

```
var dateAr = '2016-10-15'.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[0];

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy with a regex `.replace()`:

```js
var input = "2016-10-15";
var output = input.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/, "$3-$2-$1");
console.log(output);
```

You can easily allow the regex to accept several delimeters:

```js
var re = /(\d{4})[-. \/](\d\d)[-. \/](\d\d)/;

console.log("2015-10-15".replace(re, "$3-$2-$1"));
console.log("2015.10.15".replace(re, "$3-$2-$1"));
console.log("2015 10 15".replace(re, "$3-$2-$1"));
console.log("2015/10/15".replace(re, "$3-$2-$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
 var OldDate = new Date('2016-10-15');
 var NewDate = OldDate.getDate() + '-' + (OldDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + OldDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this :

```
    var MyDate = '2016-10-15';
    var formattedDate = new Date(MyDate);
    var d = formattedDate.getDate();
    var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
    m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
    var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
    alert(d + "-" + m + "-" + y);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/wpkemj4v/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get date in many formats you refer below code.

```js
var dateObj = new Date();
var div = document.getElementById("dateDemo");

div.innerHTML = "Date = " + dateObj.getDate() + 
"<br>Day = " + dateObj.getDay() + 
"<br>Full Year = " + dateObj.getFullYear() +
"<br>Hour = " + dateObj.getHours() +
"<br>Milli seconds = " + dateObj.getMilliseconds() + 
"<br>Minutes = " + dateObj.getMinutes() + 
"<br>Seconds = " + dateObj.getSeconds() + 
"<br>Time = " + dateObj.getTime();
```

```html
<div id="dateDemo"></div>
```

format the date as you want.