# Reverse the String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the string "19-12-2018" to "2018-12-19"
How can I do it?

```
var str = "19-12-2018";
    str.split('').reverse().join('')  //returns 8102-21-91"
```

how to do this?

Comment: Split by `'-'` not `''`?

Comment: Or [How to reverse date format yyyy-mm-dd using javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232218/how-to-reverse-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-using-javascript-jquery/40232597)

Comment: @JonasGrumann aww, it's looking up to you `('-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call the split function passing dash which separate each part of the string

```
str.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```

**Description of functions used**

1. [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split): The split() method turns a String into an array of strings, by separating the string at each instance of a specified separator string.

```js
const chaine = "Text";
console.log(chaine.split('')); // output ["T", "e", "x", "t"]
```

2. [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse): The reverse() method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.

```js
const characters = ["T", "e", "x", "t"];
console.log(characters.reverse()); // output ["t", "x", "e", "T"]
```

3. [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join): The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array

```js
const reverseCharacters = ["t", "x", "e", "T"];
console.log(reverseCharacters.join('')); // output "txeT"
```

Answer (score 9):

```js
var str = "19-12-2018";
var newstr = str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do `split('-')` first:

```js
var str = "19-12-2018";
str = str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
str.split('-').reverse().join('-')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var str = "19-12-2018".split('-');
var newstr=str[2]+"-"+str[1]+"-"+str[0];
```