# How to get a month in different format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datepicker to select dates from a calendar and it all works fine. However, the dates are given in numbered format when I alert them: Eg: 5-4-2017

How can I get the month in wording instead? 
Eg: 5-Apr-2017

The jquery looks like this:

```
$("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
});
```

and I used this to get the dates:

```
var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();
```

How can I get the month in a different format?

Hope you can help and [here is my pen if needed](http://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/WpqevX?editors=1111)

Comment: Check out this earlier post from the stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946475/how-to-change-date-format-using-jquery

Comment: The `date1` is stored as a date object - when you 'alert' it the browser formats it for you how it feels appropriate.  When you use get_Month() you're getting the month index (0 based).  Browsers are non-language specific (work in all languages) so won't ouput "Apr" as that's language specific.  You can use an array or a 3rd party library.

Comment: Answers very useful and It seems to work. Appreciate the support

Comment: pls see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWZbQB?editors=1111