# JQuery Convert Date fromat

Tags: jquery

I want to convert date from Format 'dd/MM/yyyy' to 'MM/dd/yyyy' and vice-versa

I tried following method for conversion

```
var val1 = '1/2/2014';
var newDate1 = new Date(val);

alert(newDate1); //returns Thu Jan 02 2014

var val2 = '2/1/2014';
var newDate2 = new Date(val);

alert(newDate2); // returns Sat Feb 01 2014
```

It is always considering above values in 'MM/dd/yy' format, in one case i need to take date format as 'dd/MM/yy' and convert it to some other

Is it possible to define the 'Date format' of the 'Date' we are going to convert?

Please suggest..

Comment: Why did you tagged question with datepicker?

Comment: Use `date.js`. It makes formatting dates in JS much easier, and is i18n compatible, should you need a multi-language version.

Comment: May be you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Comment: You can also try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI provides a way to set date format, such as:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );
```

Reference:

```
- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) function written by [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com).

Comment: post some relevant code also as link may get lost in future.

Comment: I don't think it's needed. That link contains link to the downloadable library, which is on the same domain, so if the link gets lost in future, the library will also get lost. I don't think I should post the whole library here :) And IMO this is not one of those temporary domain.

Comment: You should not post whole library but some relevant code that tell how to use library. Probably some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var days = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
var date = new Date('02-01-2014');
var day_of_week = date.getDay();
var formattedDate = date.toString(day_of_week+' M dd yyyy');
```

Hope it helps.