# Jquery AutoFormat/Complete for Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm searching for something similar to this: https://github.com/7shifts/jQueryTimeAutocomplete

But instead of time, I need some autocompletion/formatting for date.
Example: Do you type 23/9, and it's auto format to timestamp format 2014-09-23

Do you know anything?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting I think there you can find it

Comment: I'm looking for something like Excel does, you type 23/9, hit tab (or enter) and it'll format to you. But thank you, I'm still searching and gonna try some of this examples

Answer (score 0):

did it like this.

`$("#date").focusout(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var pieces = val.split('/');
        if(!pieces[2]){
            pieces[2] = new Date().getFullYear();
        }
        pieces[1] -= 1;
        console.log(pieces[2]);
        $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(pieces[2], pieces[1], pieces[0])));
    });`