# jquery date format to Nov 18, 2014

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my jquery code

```
var data='<?php echo  date('D M d Y H:i:s').""; ?>';
var someDate = new Date(data);
var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();
var someFormattedDate = mm + '/'+ dd + '/'+ y;
$("#est_date").html(someFormattedDate);
```

The output of the above code is

```
11/18/2014
```

But i need to display the output in the following date format

```
Nov 18, 2014
```

How is it possible in the jquery? Pls tell me any one knows?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5jHqU/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to print any date format within using javasscript only then you can refer below given link which have many different date formats.

[Print Any Date Format In JAVASCRIPT](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3)

Answer (score 2):

Why on earth wouldn't you just echo the date in the right format from PHP, which actually have an excellent date library

```
$("#est_date").html("<?php echo date('M d, Y'); ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $originalDate = date('D M d Y H:i:s');
$newDate = date("M d ,Y", strtotime($originalDate));
?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#est_date").html('<?php echo  $newDate; ?>'); 
});
</script>
```