# how to display this string '20150211' as '2015-02-11' using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting date as 20150211, but I want to display it like '2015-02-11' using jquery or any other way.

I tried below code in .cshtml :

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.Stats)
{
    <span class="visitDate">@item.ItemArray[0]</span>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $(".visitDate").text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Jquery doesn't have any parsing methods? I think it has. Just parse this to `datetime` or `date` (whatever it called in jquery) and format this date instead of string replacing?

Comment: Worth looking at https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (assuming you are setting the visit date text to the new format):

```
var parts = [ text.slice(0, 4), text.slice(4, 6), text.slice(6, 8) ];
$(".visitDate").text(parts.join("-"))
```

Or in C#:

```
<span class="visitDate">
@{ 
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ItemArray[0], "yyyyMMdd", null);
    <text>@date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</text>
}
</span>
```

Comment: this is useful : <span class="visitDate">
@{ 
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(item.ItemArray[0], "yyyyMMdd", null);
    <text>@date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</text>
}
</span> : thanks

Answer (score 0):

convert string into date-time and then display it in format

```
@{
   DateTime date;

   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(item.ItemArray[0],
                               "yyyyMMdd", 
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                               out date))
    {
      <span class="visitDate">date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))</span>            //valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using moment.js.

You can get this lib by run npm command: **npm install moment --save**
or by bower **bower install moment --save**
After add this lib to your page. You can use:

```
moment("20161001", "YYYYMMDD").format("DD-MM-YYYY")
```

Hope this help.