# IE Date formatting Vs Chrome (toLocaleDateString)

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer, datetime

I am just trying to achieve a simple thing, to get the current date as "dd-mm-yyyy" or "mm-dd-yyyy", so am using this:

```
var date = new Date();
$("#datefield").val(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

in IE it's giving the date using this format: "Day, Month d, yyyy"
in Chrome it's giving the date using this format: "m/d/yyyy"

How can I achieve the format that I need for all browsers?

Comment: If cross-browser consistency is the main concern, you might consider a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a library, or a [jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting).
Otherwise, your best option is to format the date yourself. It's guaranteed cross-browser.

```js
var date = new Date();
var str =
    ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    date.getFullYear();
// $("#datefield").val(str);    

alert(str);
```

Here `('0' + something).slice(-2)` is used to pad day and month with a `0`, if necessary.

Months in JavaScript are counted from 0 to 11, that's why `date.getMonth() + 1`.

The rest of the code is self-explanatory I think.

Comment: Thanks @GOTO , what libraries can I use to easily format the date? What way do people use in their projects?

Comment: @DavidHemsey Well, the top voted answer in the post I linked to suggests using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com). That's a pretty common extension in projects that already use jQuery. You could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks GOTO, I have just tried the plugin, it doesn't work in IE, and in chrome it's giving wrong value when using: $.format.date(new Date(),"mm/dd/yy");

Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidHemsey Not sure, but the syntax should be `$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date())`. Does this work?

Comment: it gives me: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined in chrome

Comment: @DavidHemsey Make sure you are including the correct versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. This works in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/pz5nLL6L/

Comment: @DavidHemsey Feel free to post your complete HTML file if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Oh, we were on 2 different pages. I was using the jQuery format library you posted its link in your answer

Comment: Is it the same one as : https://jqueryui.com/  I can't find the documentation for the validation

Comment: @DavidHemsey Ok... sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. Don't know about the other library, but the documentation for the jQuery UI function is here: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate