# MVC datepicker doubles the year

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

My MVC datepicker field is giving me the year twice. So today's date appears like this:

> 09/16/20152015

I'm wondering what's going wrong. Here's a section from my create view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a custom editor:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var value = "";
    if (Model.HasValue) {
        value = String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Value.ToString());
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "datepicker", type = "text" })
```

My Javascript Script.js file has this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use "mm/dd/yy" as your dateFormat

Comment: Just use 'yy' instead of 'yyyy'.
Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Comment: Date Formats for [jQuery Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) is `mm/dd/yy` which shows the date like `09/16/2015`, So you don't need to change it.

```
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true
        });
    });
```