# How to get custom format output from an input date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Please view the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/22ghfpac/)**.

I have a text box that inputs a date (in the format 12/11/2015) directly into the 'msg' placeholder of a paragraph.

The date displays just fine. But, I'm trying to get it to display in the following format -

```
$("#get").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#msg').html( $('input:text').val());   
    dateFormat: 'DD, MM d'
});
```

So, inputting today's date, as **12/11/2015** would yield a result of **Friday, December 11**

...but it's not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), it can accomplish what you're looking for with the right options. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21748457/798634) SO answer for usage.

Comment: @MattK - A great resource. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Javascript Date Methods to get the desired output format.. Here is the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) for reference, and here is code which gets the output you want:

```
$("#get").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var d = new Date( $('input:text').val() );
    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var day = days[d.getDay()];
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var month = months[d.getMonth()];
    var date = d.getDate();
    var output = day+", "+month+" "+date;
     $('#msg').html( output ); 
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy2h35r8/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get the stringified version of the month name and day name from the native Date object. You need to keep arrays of Month names and day names and query from that.

```
$(function(){
    $("#get").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var fDate = getDateFormatted($('input:text').val());
       $('#msg').html(fDate);   
   });

});    

function getDateFormatted(dateString)
{
  date = new Date(dateString);
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

 var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                   "August", "September", "October","November", "December"];

  var day=date.getDay();
  var dayName = days[day+1];
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

 return dayName + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex+1] + ' ' +  date.getDate();

}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/wuseza/edit?js,console,output)  is a working sample.

Comment: But, I want to display the output as (example) **Friday, December 11**, so would I just add another variable and list days of the week and then call it in the return string?

Comment: I saw your update on jsbin. It's interesting, but it's making sense.

Comment: My only question is why, when I enter today's date, **12/11/2015**, it returns a date string of **Friday, December 5**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Comment: I updated the question. I'm trying to get the output to display as **DD, MM d**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dateformat plugin for jquery. 
have a look at
[jQuery date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)