# How to Convert Date format MMM DD,YYYY to mm/dd/yyyy in jquery

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

my Date is "Dec 29, 2015 - Dec 29, 2015" and use  substring,

```
var StartDate = strDate.substring(0, 12);
```

So,

```
StartDate = Dec 29, 2015, 
  var EndDate = strDate.substring(15, 27);
```

So,

```
EndDate = Dec 29, 2015
```

Comment: You can use `.split("-")` to get two dates.

Comment: thanx for reply,but how to convert Dec 29, 2015 to 12/29/2015

Comment: Lots of info on dates here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Answer (score 3):

This might help in pure javascript

```
var date1= "DEC 29,2015";
var myDate = new Date(date1);
alert(myDate);
var d = myDate.getDate();
var m =  myDate.getMonth();
var y = myDate.getFullYear();
alert((++m) + "/" + d + "/" + y);
```

You can convert `day` and `month` to double digits with following reusable function

```
function GetTodayDate() {
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                var hh = today.getHours();
                var min = today.getMinutes();

                if (hh < 10) {
                    hh = '0' + hh;
                }
                if (min < 10) {
                    min = '0' + min;
                }

                if (dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0' + dd;
                }

                if (mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm;
                }

                today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
                return today;
            }
```

Comment: Accept as answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var StartDate= "DEC 30,2015";
 var newDate = new Date(StartDate);
 var date = newDate.getDate();
 var month =  newDate.getMonth();
 var year = newDate.getFullYear();
 
 var desiredDate = month+'/'+date+'/'+year;
    alert(desiredDate)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```