# Convert Date from YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s to H:i:s DD-MM-YYYY in Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, date, datetime

I have the following date format : `2015-02-18T07:07:25.136Z` from my database, I would like to convert it to `07:07:25 18-02-2015`. I keep on getting the following : `10:07:25 , 18-01-2015`. 
I am using the  following function to give me the  above date :

```
var order_date = item.dateordered;
var date = new Date(order_date),
    yr = date.getFullYear(),
    month = +date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
    day = +date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
    hour = +date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours(),
    minutes = +date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = +date.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds(),
    cleaned_order_date = hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' , ' + day + '-' + month + '-' + yr;
```

What is the best way to convert the date from `2015-02-18T07:07:25.136Z` to `07:07:25 , 18-02-2015` ?

Comment: You could start by fixing the syntax errors, then it might actually execute some of the code

Comment: There is no better way. You need to write your own function/method.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5250298/2269749

Answer (score 2):

you could simple use regex replace and capture groups:-

```js
var regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).\d{3}[Z]/;
var currentVal = '2015-02-18T07:07:25.136Z';

var newVal = currentVal.replace(regex, '$4:$5:$6 $3-$2-$1') //"07:07:25 18-02-2015"

alert(newVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var datestring = month + "/" + date + "/" + year + " at " + hours + ":" + mins;
```

**Or**

Refer [link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)