# Using jQuery to change date format into d-m-y

Tags: jquery

I need to change a date format taken from HTML date input and added into a text box. Currently if I am adding date as: 04-26-2016 it will be added to text box as 2016-04-26.

But what I need is to add it into my text box as : 26-04-2016.
Is their any way using jquery ?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //onee is date input:
  $("#onee").on('change', function()
  {
    var val = $("#onee").val();
    $('#one').val($('#one').val() + "- Date:" + val);
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you adding and parsing the date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)

Comment: No I saw that post and didn't helped me. Chek my edit @callback

Comment: Do you type the date manually or is it provided by some date picker?

Comment: it is from date picker

Comment: Why does this `$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());` not work?

Comment: don't know and no errors at the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a's value to your textbox.

```
var a=$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd-mm-yy", new Date("2016-04-26"));

console.log(a);
```

Output:
"26-04-2016"

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
var todaydate = new Date("2016-04-26");  //pass val varible in Date(val)
var dd = todaydate .getDate();
var mm = todaydate .getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = todaydate .getFullYear();
if(dd<10){  dd='0'+dd } 
if(mm<10){  mm='0'+mm } 
var date = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
```