# convert date as "Y-m-d" formate in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with jQuery.

I have date as `August 2, 2016` format.

Now, I want to convert this date into **Y-m-d** format as **2016-08-02**.

So, What jQuery should I have to write to resolve this problem?

Comment: Every conceivable JavaScript date formatting question has been asked and answered a dozen times over here on on SO (and thousands of times on the web at large). Please search before posting.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have date-specific functions, try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: I really recommend checking out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you're doing a lot of work with dates. JavaScript dates/times can be quite a nightmare, moment.js makes it really easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code for Y-m-d

```
var date    = new Date(userDate),
yr      = date.getFullYear(),
month   = date.getMonth(),
day     = date.getDate(),
newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
console.log(newDate);
```

or this for YYYY-mm-dd

```
var date    = new Date(userDate),
yr      = date.getFullYear(),
month   = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
day     = date.getDate()  < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate()  : date.getDate(),
newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {         

    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();                                    
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based         
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();             

    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
 };  

d = new Date();
$('#today').html(d.yyyymmdd());
```

[check here](http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-javascript-function-to-format-the-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd/)