# JQuery for dynamically generated input fields

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with the following; I have a dynamically generated table form. In one of the columns I have a select input with some options and in the following column I have an input field for Timestamp that should be automatically filled out with the current date as soon as the user selects one of the options. I have the following code, however, the timestamp is either only generated for the very first row (in case when I use id for input field)  or for all of the rows (in case when I use class for input field). I would need the timestamp to be filled only in the same row as the select drop down list is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<select  class='Status'> 
  <option value= '1'> Option1 </option>
  <option value= '2'> Option2 </option>
</select> 

<input type=text class='TimeStamp'/>
```

Then for my JQuery I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Status').on('change', function() {
        $('.TimeStamp').val("CurrentDate");
});
});
```

Comment: HTML code with you table is more helpfull, or create jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Status').on('change', function() {
        // get current row
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        // find .TimeStanp in the current row and set value
        row.find('.TimeStamp').val("CurrentDate");         
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to format Date() that would return the date in this format: 09-14-2016 10:11:51 ? I tried the following code but it didn't work: 
`var d = new Date(); 
var h = d.getHours();
           h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

           var m = d.getMinutes();
             m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

             var s = d.getSeconds();
             s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

           datetext = datetext + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;`

Comment: Take a look for [jQuery date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event [**delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like following.

```
$(document).on('change', '.Status', function() {
    $('.TimeStamp').val("CurrentDate");
});
```