# Edit date/time string via Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the a string that is loaded dynamically. The string contains information that is the date that a post is published. Unfortunately it's in a format that is not suitable for the content its added to. I would like to be able to dynamically edit the string so that only the date is showing and it appears in a day/month/year format. The following is an example of a string:

```
<div>2016-01-14T10:30:37+02:00</div>
```

How can I format the string so that it always looks like the following:

```
<div>14/01/2016</div>
```

Comment: Easy.... `$('div').text('14/01/2016');` Sure, it's not perfect, but it's better than *your* attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)

Comment: i presume he wants to extract the date  for each day, month and year and then change it

I would suggest maybe some regex.(even though i hate it)

Place the year in one var, Month in another and day in another and then change to contents like musefan suggested

Comment: You'll need to post the javascript code that produces what you have.

Comment: With [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) library you pass that string as argument and it will return the date on the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="date-string">2016-01-14T10:30:37+02:00</div>
<div class="date-string">2013-02-16T10:30:37+02:00</div>
<div class="date-string">2017-03-15T10:30:37+02:00</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var d, newDateFormat;

function getZero(number){
 if(number < 10) return '0' + number;
 return number;
}

$('.date-string').each(function(){
 d = new Date($(this).html());

 newDateFormat = getZero(d.getDate()) + '/' + getZero(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();

 $(this).html(newDateFormat);
});
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works but I have multiple instances of the string on the page. With this code it replaces all the instances with the same date.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, it works for multiple string in the DOM