# Convert today's date to given format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetime-format, date-formatting

I am trying to convert today's date in particular format and this date format can be anything like - dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy.mm.dd and so on

```
var date = new Date();
var todaysDate = date.toString('mm/dd/yyyy');
```

However, this code is not working.
Is there any other way to get it done.

I am looking for a common way where today's date can be converted to any given format

Comment: `console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date()));`

Comment: Caution with Intl, it's not supported by all browsers (see browser compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). You can use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Your comment that "I dont want a particular format. It should get changed to any given format like yyyy.mm.dd or dd-mm-yyy." should be made clear in the question.

Comment: I am looking for a common way where todays date can be converted to any given format

Comment: @Marc, thanks for that link. I'm comparing it to https://caniuse.com/#search=intl which presents it in a more favorable light. Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format appears to show a more specific view related to the format portion of DateTimeFormat.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/docs/) -- my go to JS date library -- to do something like

```
Moment (new Date ()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Or, if you know the form of the datetime format of the input string

```
Moment(string, "DD/MM/yyyy").format("MM/DD/YYYY")
```

MomentJS has other advantages too like adding time or dates or diffing two datetimes.

**Alternatively**, you could use Date Class functions to get parts of a Datetime and custom print or format them.

See [StackOverflow format JS Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is useful for u.

```js
  var currentDt = new Date();
    var mm = currentDt.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = currentDt.getDate();
    var yyyy = currentDt.getFullYear();
    var date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    alert(date);
```

Comment: This will work but I dont want a particular format. It should get changed to any given format like yyyy.mm.dd or dd-mm-yyy. I dont want to write code for everything. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: I think jquery might not support this by default. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11261274 in this question they used a plug-in to do this.