# How to print only dates with the weekdays between two specific dates in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I'm trying in jQuery to print the number of the dates and Full weekday on particular day but it gives me the output shows like below:-

Output

```
[Fri Jun 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
 Sat Jun 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
 ......,
 ......, //further till end date
]
```

The code I'm using is :-

```
 var start = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate"),
  end = $("#txtToDate").datepicker("getDate"),
  currentDate = new Date(start.getTime()),
  between = []
;

while (currentDate <= end) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
    console.log(between);
```

Edited code:-

```
var start = $("#txtFromDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('M dd yyyy', new Date())),
end = $("#txtToDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('M dd yyyy', new Date())),
currentDate = new Date(start.getTime()),
between = []
;

while (currentDate <= end) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(between);
```

I tried this code too but not getting any useful output but it gives an error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: start.getTime is not a function
>
> at HTMLButtonElement. (setschedule:227)
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

Output I need is:-

```
 [Friday, 06-01-2018,
  Saturday, 06-02-2018,
  ......,
  ......, //further till end date
 ]
```

How can I will get my output Any help can be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Look at date formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting

Comment: @zanerock i tried this code i edit my question can you help me?

Comment: The [`formatDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) returns a string, not a date. So you probably want  to format the date when you do the push, and then have an array of formated strings representing dates: `between.push($.datepicker.formatDate('M dd yyyy', currentDate));`

Comment: @zanerock what about days?

Comment: Are you asking how to print the names of the days? Check out the `formatDate` docs linked in previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

After you build the array, use .pop() to remove the last element, and use .shift() to remove the first element.  That should leave you with only the dates between.

Comment: I'm confussed what you are talking can you help me to do this.

Comment: Oops, on further review I think I misunderstood your question.  Sorry!