# jquery ui datepicker error on beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to implement a event calendar using jquery-ui's datepicker. I've successfully installed the datepicker and it shows up and working. the problem appears when I try to register the `beforeShowDay` handler. Like this:

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay : function(){ }} );
```

I receive the following error in jquery-ui -file: `ba is undefined`.
when I output something int the function, the first four times it outputs but then I receive the error.

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay : function(){ console.log('test') }} );
```

Output:

```
// test
// test
// test
// test
// ba is undefined
```

if anyone has a clue what's the problem, please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add this `return [true,'']`

**Like this**

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       console.log('test');
       return [true,''];
    }
});
```

Ref.
http://osdir.com/ml/jquery-ui/2009-02/msg00349.html

Comment: Yep, I just found the exact same source. Thanks