# How do I highlight a specific date when viewing a jquery datepicker calendar?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker to display a calendar in month view (only one month is visibile). I want it to hightlight (by default) a specific date. For example, if I'm viewing an 'event page' on my website, then I want it to show the calendar with the day of that event highlighted. I cannot get it to work. It shows the calendar, but it always highlights today's date, not the date I have set. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ defaultDate: "07-11-2012" });
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385332/jquery-datepicker-highlight-dates) might help

Comment: I looked at that one, but I'm not trying to highlight a range of dates, just one specific date. I tried modifying that code, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "1/2/2013");
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The calendar doesn't even display anymore.