# How to set date range in jQuery Datepicker and set it as a default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

1. I need to set the "start date" to +1 day from the current day.
2. And +3 days from the "start date" for the "end day"
3. (optional) Highlight the trailing days

[image]

Fiddle can be found here: http://jsbin.com/icuduv/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you can simply do it like this

```
var d = new Date(); d.setDate( d.getDate() + 1 );
$('#txtStartDate').datepicker('setDate', d); 
d = new Date(); d.setDate( d.getDate() + 4 );
$('#txtEndDate').datepicker('setDate', d);
```

i have updated your demo as well have a look [Here](http://jsbin.com/icuduv/7)

for highlighting dates you can use the [beforeShowDay](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) event. It will get called for each date that needs to be shown in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Get the date values using something along these lines:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+3);

$("#startDateInput").val(startDate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));
$("#endDateInput").val(endDate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));
```

This question could help with the highlighting:

[Highlight dates in specific range with jQuery's datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385332/jquery-datepicker-highlight-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one

```
$(function() {
  var $defaultDate = new Date(); 
  $defaultDate.setDate( $defaultDate.getDate() + 1 );
  $('#txtStartDate').datepicker({defaultDate:   $defaultDate}).val(($defaultDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + $defaultDate.getDate() + '/' +  $defaultDate.getFullYear()); 
  $defaultDate.setDate( $defaultDate.getDate() + 3 );
  $('#txtEndDate').datepicker({defaultDate: $defaultDate}).val(($defaultDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + $defaultDate.getDate() + '/' +   $defaultDate.getFullYear()); 
});
```