# Need to highlight range of dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to display an inline datepicker in this i have a start date and an end date. I want to highlight the dates in between them.

Comment: none of the solution worked for me.

Comment: You need to be more specific *why* the other solutions won't work for you. Otherwise you're just going to get the same answers.

Comment: only start and end date got highligted in those solutions. i want the whole range of dates in between them to get highlighted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI datepicker [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function and inside it check if the date must be highlighted according to your range.

> A function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with
>   [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is
>   selectable, [1](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) equal to a CSS class name or "" for the default
>   presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is
>   called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

Example:

```
var date1 = new Date(2013, 4, 6);
var date2 = new Date(2013, 4, 17);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            debugger
            if (date >= date1 && date <= date2) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-error', ''];
            }
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zz9u4/